# .htaccess rewrite path of php file

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I got an installation of owncloud that exhibits strange behaviour. My biggest problem currently is that the installation is at subdomain.domain.com but the file share tool removes the subdomain from the url.

e.g.:
Correct link would be:
http://subdomain.domain.com/public.php?service=files&t=download

But the user gets output this:
http://domain.com/public.php?service=files&t=download

Can I fix this by using htaccess rewrite?

Comment: Dropping the subdomain is rather odd. Are you sure it isn't doing something like `http://domain.com/subdomain_dir/public.php?...`? If so, a simple R=301 rewrite will probably clean up the domain. Beyond that, it's something you'll likely have to take up with the hosting service (unless it's _your_ code doing the dropping).

Comment: mine runs on subdomain without any problems. Is in your config the right domain? (config/config.php)